# How to include a flash video in angularjs page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flash

I have an angularjs generated html page, and want to embedd a flash video in it.

Problem: the video url is dynamically provided by a backend, so I tried binding it as follows:

```
<div ng-bind-html="{{my.video.html}}"></div>
```

Result that gets rendered:

```
<div ng-bind-html="<object classid="..." codebase="..." flashvideo...><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"...>"></div>
```

But I don't see anything on the page.

If I'd just pase the `<object..` html code statically into the webpage, it would work.

So what am I missing when using angularjs?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282859/angular-directive-to-display-flash-via-object-tag-causes-flash-to-attempt-to-l

Comment: @SANN could you give an example how I could include my dynamic flash html content into the directive presented in the referred question? I mean, the solution there presented uses a static `<object><embed>` html template where only the `src` tag is dynamically filled. But for me, the whole html content is dynamic!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do.

**HTML**

```
<div id="videoDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      document.getElementById("videoDiv").innerHTML ='<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="name.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">';
 });
```